# Closure as a function argument

Tags: php, closures

Currently I have the following function:

```
function nestedClosure($query, $values)
{
    $callback = function($q) use (&$values,&$callback) {
        if( !$values) $q->method();
        else $q->method(array_shift($values),$callback);
    };
    $callback($query);
}
```

I would like to inject, coming from a third function argument, a closure where now lies `$q->method();`

Is this possible with php?

Answer (score 0):

Could `call_user_func` solve your problem?

```
<?php
call_user_func(array($obj, $method_name), $parameter /* , ... */);
call_user_func(array(&$obj, $method_name), $parameter /* , ... */); // PHP 4
?>
```